# Bayesian network Classifier

Tags: c++, classification, bayesian-networks

I'm looking for an Open Source  Bayesian network Classifier library written in c++. Would appreciate any help in finding one.

Comment: have you tried googling?

Comment: yes,i search it on google,but not find

Comment: @unkulunkulu - **My** Google search pulled this result near the top, and I'd like to think StackOverflow (or another StackExchange site, if this one's not appropriate for this question) would be a *first* choice to go to find the answer to a question such as this.  Perhaps it's better to suggest a different StackExchange site for this question, rather than implying that *any* StackExchange site would be inappropriate (i.e., that googling for another source is more appropriate than asking/answering the question on a StackExchange site)?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum, I just asked if some research was done before and what it might have revealed (i.e. not open source or not c++ or not fitting a particular requirement) that's all :)

Comment: @unkulunkulu - Actually, you asked whether the original poster tried googling.  I think a better way to ask that question is, well, exactly how you've just phrased it in your comment to me.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum, while I agree, do you really think that schooling authors of 2 year old comments is the best idea of spending time? :)

Comment: @unkulunkulu I do, because I think it's important that current folks who land on this result see a counterweight to a posting like that.  Nothing at all personal.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a subject I'm altogether familiar with, but a couple of minutes Googling found this:

http://genie.sis.pitt.edu/

As I'm not too familiar with the topic I haven't actually used the software, so I can't actually say whether its much good or not - I'll leave that for you to decide.

There's a list of other links that may be of interest here:

http://ksvanhorn.com/bayes/free-bayes-software.html

Comment: @titiri Ehm, you're looking for a Classifier, but not for classification?

Answer (score 0):

There are five C++ libraries [here](https://github.com/topics/bayesian-networks?l=c%2B%2B). Although I have not used any of them, they seem rather general (e.g., https://github.com/godai0519/BayesianNetwork) and might not include some of the standard classification algorithms you might be looking for.

There is a list of libraries [here](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Software/bnsoft.html), although last updated in 2014.